# How can i get to my app by pressing back?

Tags: android

In my login process if my device time and server time don't match a alert box appear and when i click that box it bring to my device time setting.I do this by the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now  am try to get back my app loging page by pressing device back button.Unfortunately i can't.It bring me to device page not my app page.How can i do that??
Here is my code snip:

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: your code and my code do the same things.
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior what you are looking for. Pressing back button from Settings page should take you back to your app unless you've killed/closed the app explicitly. Have a look at your code and look for if you have done anything like closing your app (something like using `finish();` in your activity's onPause() or onResume() method).

Comment: Actually in my manifest.xml file android:noHistory was set "true".Thats why i can't get back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ Shahrair Nazim Real you can try this hope this can help you..

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(alertDialog.isShowing()){
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.I find the reason and comment above at Sudip podder's comment.